# Email address is appending the DF servicename for Facebook OAuth Service

Tags: dreamfactory

Email address is appending the DF servicename for Facebook OAuth Service. Here is output from service callback after facebook/google OAuth.

```
{
“session_token”: “xxxxx”,
“session_id”: “xxxxx”,
“id”: 121,
“name”: “Sree Iasdf”,
“first_name”: “Sree”,
“last_name”: “Iasdf”,
“email”: "isree+SPTPFacebookOAuth@hotmail.com",
“is_sys_admin”: null,
“last_login_date”: “2019-02-28 07:18:21”,
“host”: “abcdef”,
“oauth_token”: “abcdef”
}
```

Thanks,
Sree

Answer (score 0):

Hi DFTeam,

Please keep the documentation more accurate  - https://github.com/dreamfactorysoftware/df-oauth/blob/master/src/Services/BaseOAuthService.php#L202

DF OAuth service never return the actual email address of the user. It will always return ShadowOAuthUser such as `$emailId . '+' . $serviceName . '@' . $domain;`

Thank you for wonderful tool.

Thanks,

Sree